# Count number of check to build the list

Tags: prolog

I have an error when i count number of check in order to build the list.

Here is my code:

```
  find(_R1, _R2, [], [],0).
  find(R1, R2, [[Mark, CName] | T], L,N) :-
     (  (R1 =< Mark, Mark =< R2),N is N+1
     -> L = [CName | L1]
     ;  L = L1
     ),
     find(R1, R2, T, L1,N).
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N is N+1 is always false in Prolog , Prolog is not C, you MUST write N1 is N+1, because when N is unified with a value, it can't be changed, so N is never equal to N+1.
Your code must be written like that, the recursion must be called before the calculus of N.

```
find(_R1, _R2, [], [],0).

find(R1, R2, [[Mark, CName] | T], L,N):-
  find(R1, R2, T, L1,N1),
  ( (R1 =< Mark, Mark =< R2)
   ->  L = [CName | L1],N is N1+1
   ;   L = L1, N = N1).
```

[EDIT] In your post, N has no value when you call N is N+1, because N gets a value after the return of the call of **find(R1, R2, T, L1,N).**

Comment: is this return the number of check in order to build the list?

Comment: No it's the number of checks that succeed, I think you can modify easily the code to find the number of all the checks.